# how to insert multiple array in mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, insert

Im trying to insert array in mysql table... but my code doesn't work

```
$File = 'testfile.csv';
$arrResult  = array();
$handle     = fopen($File, "r");
$row = 0;
if(empty($handle) === false) {
    while(($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE){
        $arrResult[] = $data;
        $num = count($data); //2100 resultats in my testfile
        $row++;
        if($row>1){ //ignore header line 
            for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) { //start loop
                $sql = '
                    INSERT INTO MyTable (name, class, level, ability) 
                    VALUES ("'.$data[0].'","'.$data[1].'","'.$data[2].'","'.$data[3].'")
                ';
                $Add=$db->query($sql);  
            }
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
};
```

Result in Mytable: 
1,Hero1, Warrior, 65, vitality;
2,Hero1, Warrior, 65, vitality;
3,Hero1, Warrior, 65, vitality;
4,Hero1, Warrior, 65, vitality;
...

Comment: What isn't correct with that result? What result were you expecting?

Comment: Use prepared statements fro this.

Comment: Get rid of your `for` loop, the `fgetcsv` already gets one line at a time

Comment: @AlexBarker here the content of testfile : 
Hero1; Warrior; 65; vitality;
Hero2; Cleric; 32; Magic;
Hero3; Ninja; 78; Escape;
Hero4; Paladin; 21; Fury;

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You don't need the inner `for` loop. You're inserting the same row multiple times, since `$count` is the number of fields in the CSV.

And instead of checking `$row` each time through the loop, you can simply read the first line and ignore it before the loop.

```
if(empty($handle) === false) {
    fgets($handle); // skip header line
    while(($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE){
        $sql = '
            INSERT INTO MyTable (name, class, level, ability) 
            VALUES ("'.$data[0].'","'.$data[1].'","'.$data[2].'","'.$data[3].'")
        ';
        $Add=$db->query($sql);  
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
// remove `for` loop
if($row>1){ //ignore header line 
    $sql = '
        INSERT INTO MyTable (name, class, level, ability) 
        VALUES ("'.$data[0].'","'.$data[1].'","'.$data[2].'","'.$data[3].'")
    ';
    $Add=$db->query($sql);  
}
```

And of course move to **prepared statements** to make your code more secure.

Comment: Hi, Thx for your help, result is  Undefined offset when i remove loop

Comment: Please be kind and provide __full message__. We're here not guess them.

Comment: oups ! Here the full message : 
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in insert_action.php on line 15  
the line is :   VALUES ("'.$data[0].'","'.$data[1].'","'.$data[2].'","'.$data[3].'")

Comment: Output your `$data` variable and check what's wrong with it.